# Break inside a function with for

Tags: python, python-3.x

(Python 3.10.4)

I have a **for** condition and inside this for a have a **function** that need a break and go back to the top like "continue" do, but i can't use break outside a loop, how can i go back to the top of the code? I will use this function so many times after and i don't want to have so many if in my code

```
import time

def function1():

 if pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('file.png')

 pyautogui.moveTo(x=612, y263)
 time.sleep(1)
 break
```

How can i break the code in this case:

```
for c in range (0,10):
print('begin for')

#FUNCTION
function1():
#
#
#REST OF THE CODE
```

Comment: This code is neither indented correctly nor syntactically correct making it very hard to provide help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to imagine what you meant by 'break the code' with your incorrect code indentations. I guess you meant to break the for loop
when the function breakes.

Use a variable out side the function to indicate when you're done with your function.

And check for the value of the variable within the for loop to break or pass

```
br = 0
def function1():

    if pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('file.png')
        pyautogui.moveTo(x=612, y=263)
        br = 1 
        time.sleep(1)
        return 0



for c in range (0,10):
    print('begin for')  
    #FUNCTION
    function1()

    if br == 1:
        break
    else:
        pass
    
#
#
#REST OF THE CODE
```

Comment: The problem is that when the function finishes executing it continues with the rest of the code, and I needed it to come back to the top when the function finishes

Comment: You need to go back to the beginning of the for loop or back to top of the entire code when function finishes?

Comment: Just go back to the beginning of the loop after the execute the function, if the function doesn't find the "file 1.png" i need he just continue with the rest of the code

Comment: Replace `break` with `continue` and `pass` with `break`in for loop. Sorry for mistake.

Comment: It works when i replace break with continue and if i keep "else: pass", thank you so much!!